# Add custom column to Datagrid in admin-on-rest

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, progress-bar, admin-on-rest

I've created an admin panel in React.js using [`admin-on-rest`](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/). I have a page showing a user list pulling data from an api. I need to add a custom column at the end of each row of that table that will display a progress bar for each user.

I'm using a module called [`rc-progress`](https://github.com/react-component/progress) to generate the progress bar. Here's an example display on a separate page currently from the user list:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'rc-progress';

var Progress = React.createClass({
render: function render() {

    return (
       <Line percent="40" strokeWidth="1" strokeColor="#38bcd5" />
    );
}
});

export default Progress;
```

I'm not sure how to append a custom column to a Datagrid in admin-on-rest to add in that progress bar.

Here's the code I have for the User list which is displaying the data from the API correctly. I've added a comment where I'd want to add the progress bar:

```
import React from 'react';
import { List, Datagrid, TextField} from 'admin-on-rest';
import { Line } from 'rc-progress';

export const UserList = (props) => (
<List {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
        <TextField source="firstName" />
        <TextField source="lastName" />
        <TextField source="email" />
        <TextField source="phone" />
        <TextField source="type" />

        //I'd like to add the progress bar below:
        //<Line percent="40" strokeWidth="1" strokeColor="#38bcd5" />

    </Datagrid>
</List>

);
```

export default UserList;

Any help is much appreciated!

### Update (Solution)

So on the recommendation of Gildas I've tried to use the FunctionField.  Here is the working version of the code. (The progress bar has hard-coded values right now)

```
import React from 'react';
import { List, Datagrid, TextField} from 'admin-on-rest';
import { Line } from 'rc-progress';
import { FunctionField } from 'admin-on-rest'

export const UserList = (props) => (
<List {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
        <TextField source="firstName" />
        <TextField source="lastName" />
        <TextField source="email" />
        <TextField source="phone" />
        <TextField source="type" />

        //Here is the working version below:
        <FunctionField label="Progress" render= {function render() { return ( <Line percent="40" strokeWidth="1" strokeColor="#38bcd5" />);}} />

    </Datagrid>
</List>

);


export default UserList;
```

Here's a current screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of added column]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FunctionField` should do the trick: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html#functionfield

If not, have you tried following the custom field documentation ?

Comment: Thanks Gildas.  I've updated the question with what I tried for the FunctionField. I'm not sure if my syntax on the render prop is correct or if I can even try to use code from rc-progress in that render function. Let me know if have any thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware of http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/linear-progress ? That would save you an additional dependency :)

Comment: And thanks for posting this update, that will help others !

Comment: I haven't looked at linear-progress although it looks like an animated progress bar based on page/component load. I'm not sure how to override the default behavior to show a static percentage.

Comment: `<LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={myValue} />`